# How much are index providers accountable to their clients?

Tags: united-states, investing, index-fund, market-indexes

Criticism on index providers:

> The increasing influence of indices means that some critics argue that
>   benchmark providers such as MSCI are too powerful, given that
>   promotions or relegations can send or sap billions of dollars from a
>   country’s stock market.

Response from [Fernandez](https://www.msci.com/www/leadership/henry-fernandez/0129938956) of MSCI:

> “The concept that index companies are so powerful and influential
>   ignores the fact that we are agents of our clients. The minute we go
>   against the wishes of our clients, it will be the beginning of the
>   end,” he said.

I'm wondering which of these two perspectives is closer to reality.

### Question

Is there anything in historical precedence for us to take Fernandez at his word?

- If so, then why are critics still dubious?
- If not, then what could MSCI do to appease such critics?

Comment: where are the quotes from?

Comment: I suspect the question may be too subjective, but... should you not also be questioning whether what some [un-sourced] critics have to say has any validity (as opposed, say, to just being controversial or a case of sour grapes if they've lost out)?